# Running two commands from bash script in one process (conda)

Tags: linux, bash, conda

I'm trying to write a bash script that includes deactivating and removing a conda environment. Here's an example, `remove_env.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the conda command available in bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"

# Deactivate environment
conda deactivate

# Remove environment
conda remove --name my_env --all --yes
```

The environment must be deactivated in order to remove it.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I perform this in the terminal:

```sh
$ conda activate my_env
$ ./remove_env.sh

CondaEnvironmentError: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again
```

I think the issue has to do with [forking](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_03.html) - essentially, the environment gets deactivated in one process, but then the remove call is run in another process, which doesn't have the environment deactivated. But I'm not entirely sure.

Some notes:

- I can't use `source remove_env.sh` - I must be able to use `./remove_env.sh`
- I've tried this with no success:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the conda command available in bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"

# Deactivate and remove environment
conda deactivate && conda remove --name my_env --all --yes
```

- I call the command `conda activate my_env` in my `~./bashrc`
- I can't use aliases - it must be a bash script

Comment: Does the manual on [Deactivating an environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment) not help?  It looks like you should activate the default environment with `conda activate` (and no arguments), before doing the remove of what was the active environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan for the answer in the comments. You're totally right, I completely overlooked that blue note in the conda manual. I was able to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the conda command available in bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"

# Activate the environment
conda activate my_env

# Deactivate environment
conda deactivate

# Remove environment
conda remove --name my_env --all --yes
```

I think it works whether you `conda activate` with or without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using Conda's `run` tool, one could avoid manual activation. That is, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env conda run bash

conda env remove -n my_env -y
```